# SSRS post back after action

Tags: reporting-services

On my report I have a table with an action link that opens another table, like this:

Type | QTY 
xxxx  |  10
yyyy  |  2

My action is on QTY numbers and it opens a new detailed table, similar to this:

Type | Name | Detail 
xxxx | Pasd |  text
xxxx | Etytt |  text

The problem is that my first table is opened after I choose some parameters and, after I click the action link on my first table, it shows correctly the second one, but loses the parameters for the first one, showing all the content like I havent filtered before.

Is there a way to keep the parameters for the first table or 'do no post back' it after I click on the action link?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was quite simple, but it took me a long time to realize as I am definetly not an expert on this..

So..

When you add the parameters to the action, you need to write new paramaters with the exactly same name as your original ones and write in the fuction, the value of the actual field.

The problem I had first is that my procedure only receive 4 parameters, but i needed to send 6 parameters. The extra 2 was from my original filters.